# Wsus install updates with non admins

Tags: windows, wsus, update

I have an Wsus 3.0 sp1 on Windows 2003 Server installed on a domain.

Problem:

when i'm logged as an admin i have the "little balloon" pooping up to install updates, but when i'm logged as an "normal user" (non admins) it doesn't show nothing.

I'm using updates by Windows update policy, and i've enabled the option:
"Allow non-administrators to receive update notifications"

But it doesn't work.

Anyone as any experience, tip or trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the Group Policy has applied to the computer you're using?

You can check via several methods, including the Resultant Set of Policy (RSOP.msc), the Group Policy Results wizard in GPMC, or via the Registry entry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\windows\WindowsUpdate\Elevate NonAdmins = REG_DWORD 1).

Comment: Ok, the client needed a reboot ;P
you are right, the rsop and the registry show that it's applied.
I logged as an normal user and the agent pooped up the update ballon.
thx